# How to implement rownum in mysql with spring JDBC

Tags: mysql, spring-jdbc, named-parameters

I am executing a query with spring-jdbc such a way to get rownum with each row.
The query I am using is

```
sql=SET @pos=0; 
select * from ( 
SELECT @pos:=@pos+1 pos,e.* from employee e where department_id=:department_id 
order by DOB desc) emp  
where pos > :inPos limit :limit
```

This is working fine when I am executing this query in some MySql IDE, but failed to execute the same with spring jdbc.

The code I am using in Java is

```
MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
paramSource.addValue("pos", 0);
paramSource.addValue("department_id", 10);
paramSource.addValue("inPos", 1);
paramSource.addValue("limit", 10);
List<Employee> emps = (List<Employee>) myDao.executeQueryByNamedParameterJdbcTemplate(sql,paramSource, Employee.class);
```

In `myDao` I have:

```
public <T> Object executeQueryByNamedParameterJdbcTemplate(String sql, MapSqlParameterSource paramSource, Class<T> t) throws PersistenceException{
        Object object = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, paramSource, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(t));
        return object;  
    }
```

It is giving a BadSQLGrammer Exception

Comment: I dont know JAVA but is it possible that the library doesnt accept multiple queries.

Comment: May be that is the case, But in Spring-JDBC there must be some work around but not found any .. Thats why posted here, if not get any answer. then my last step will be create a stored proc and execute the same with Java, that will work for sure.